# wall receptical

Tags: electrical

Pulled this out of my mobil home wall. Never seen anything like it. Doesnt have any side posts, has 4 sets of clamp holes. Top set of holes had power wire (BLACK) going in, neutral wire (WHITE) comming out. Second set of holes had BLACK wire going in, BLACK wire going out. Third set holes had BLACK wire comming in, WHITE wire comming out. Having little bit of problem with black in, black out. Thinking it would be like a built in pig tail. Any thoughts would be gratefully accepted. 
Cant get picture to upload.

Comment: You really do need to upload a picture... This is really difficult to determine just from the description.

Comment: SE app doesn't upload right, try a web browser...